# How to exit a module before it has finished parsing?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a module that imports a module, but in some cases the module being imported may not exist. After the module is imported there is a class inherits from a class the imported module. If I was to catch the `ImportError` exception in the case the module doesn't exist, how can I stop Python from parsing the rest of the module? I'm open to other solutions if that's not possible.

Here is a basic example (selfaware.py):

```
try:
    from skynet import SkyNet
except ImportError:
    class SelfAwareSkyNet():
        pass
    exit_module_parsing_here()

class SelfAwareSkyNet(SkyNet):
    pass
```

The only ways I can think to do this is:

- Before importing the `selfaware.py` module, check if the `skynet` module is available, and simply pass or create a stub class. This will cause DRY if `selfaware.py` is imported multiple times.
- Within `selfaware.py` have the class defined withing the `try` block. e.g.:

  ```
  try:
      from skynet import SkyNet
      class SelfAwareSkyNet(SkyNet):
          pass
  except ImportError:
      class SelfAwareSkyNet():
          pass
  ```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?  Does it not work?  Does it get an error?

Comment: Is there an echo in here?? What's with all the exact duplicate answers? And why do both newer duplicates have higher scores than the old?

Comment: @MuMind I guess I didn't notice that hyperboreean's answer was edited after it was initially incorrect. I have reaccepted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
try:
   from skynet import SkyNet
   inherit_from = SkyNet
except ImportError:
   inherit_from = object

class SelfAwareSkyeNet(inherit_from):
    pass
```

This works only if the implementation do not differ.

**Edit:** New solution after comment.

Answer (score 7):

try: supports an else: clause

```
try:
    from skynet import SkyNet

except ImportError:
    class SelfAwareSkyNet():
        pass

else:
    class SelfAwareSkyNet(SkyNet):
        pass
```